# Can I accept a HttpPostedFileBase as part of a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, viewmodel, forms

I am setting up a view and ViewModel to accept some data and a File. But when I look at the returned model, I do not see a file.

Here's my ViewModel:

```
public class ResourceReviewViewModel
{
    public Guid ResourceReviewId { get; set; }
    //....
    [Display(Name="Review Document File")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ReviewFile { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

My controller to handle the submit:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult ResourceReview(ResourceReviewViewModel model)
{
    //...
    return View(model); // model.ReviewFile is null
}

@model PublicationSystem.ViewModels.ResourceReviewViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Submit Your Review</h4>
        <hr/>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestReviewId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewFile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" id="ReviewFile" name="ReviewFile" value="ActionHandlerForForm" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The model comes back with values, but the file property is NULL. The HTML for the Input I copied from another page, so I'm not sure I need `value="ActionHandlerForForm"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I think in your example you're just missing `multipart/form-data`

Try this (replace "Index" and "Home" to the View/Controller you have):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
...
}
```